# Do we have an equivariant Newlander-Nirenberg theorem for finite group action?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $X$ be a $2n$-dimensional $C^{\infty}$-manifold, let $G$ be a finite group acting smoothly on $X$. Let $J: TX\to TX$ be a map such that $J^2=-id$ and
$g_*Jg^{-1}_*=J$ for any $g\in G$.

We can extend $J$ to a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $J: T_{\mathbb{C}}X\to T_{\mathbb{C}}X. $Let $T^{0,1}X$ be the $-1$ eigenspace of $J$. We call $J$ is *integrable* if $[T^{0,1}X,T^{0,1}X]\subset T^{0,1}X$.

> > My question is: do we have a $G$-equivariant Newlander-Nirenberg theorem? More precisely, if $J$ is integrable, then is it true that $X$ is a complex manifold with $G$-acting holomorphically?

Comment: Viewing $g$ as a smooth map $X \to X$, do you mean $g_*Jg_*^{-1} = J$? Also, an almost complex structure is a map $J : TX \to TX$, not $T_{\mathbb{C}}X \to T_{\mathbb{C}}X$ (of course, the former extends to the latter).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese You are right. I made the edit according to your comments.

Comment: In that case, the answer to your question is yes. If $J$ is integrable, then $X$ is a complex manifold, and a map $g : X \to X$ is holomorphic if and only if $g_*J = Jg_*$. This condition on $g_*$ is equivalent to the Cauchy-Riemann equations for $g$ in smooth coordinates obtained as the real and imaginary parts of holomorphic coordinates, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoholomorphic_curve#Analogy_with_the_classical_Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) for the one-dimensional case.